# How to store recursive function value in array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I want to store the data variables (String[]) to variable results in ArrayList, and then the final results of recursive function is ArrayList results. in this case return [[ani,budi],[ani,cici],[budi,cici]]. Anyone can help me?

```
static void combinationUtil(String arr[], String data[], int start,
                                    int end, int index, int r, ArrayList<String[]> results)
        {
            if (index == r){
                results.add(data);
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
                return;
            }

            for (int i=start; i<=end && end-i+1 >= r-index; i++){
                data[index] = arr[i];
                combinationUtil(arr, data, i+1, end, index+1, r, results);
            }
        }

        public static void main (String[] args) {
            String arr[] = {"ani", "budi", "cici"};
            int r = 2;
            int n = arr.length;
            String data[] = new String[r];
            ArrayList<String[]> results = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            combinationUtil(arr, data, 0, n-1, 0, r, results);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the line of adding the array to the list and make a copy, because the saved array is changing in other iterations

```
results.add(Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length));
```

, To be like this:

```
    static void combinationUtil(String arr[], String data[], int start, int end, int index, int r,
            ArrayList<String[]> results) {
        if (index == r) {
            results.add(Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length));
            return;
        }

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            data[index] = arr[i];
            combinationUtil(arr, data, i + 1, end, index + 1, r, results);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :), could you approve the answer :D

Comment: Is it possible to change from "static void" to "static ArrayList<String[]>"?

Comment: Do you mean to return the ArrayList from the function?

Comment: Yupp.. is it possible ??